# FormsAuthentication working in every browser except for IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, forms-authentication

This certainly is a strange one...

I have an ASP.net 4.0, C# website that has a login page using FormsAuthentication to handle user access.  There's also code throughout the site that boots the user back to the login page whenever a session times out or something else that requires them to login again happens.  This is all really basic stuff that I've done about a dozen times before.

I know this whole process is working, because I've been able to login to the site running through VS2010 on EVERY browser I tried.  It also works perfectly fine when it's sitting on the development server using Chrome, Firefox, Safari (Mac), and two Cellphone browsers.  The only thing I've had a problem with is Internet Explorer.

Now, this one is a bit hard to debug considering it works in IE locally but not on the server.  The fact that it also works in other browsers on the server is also sort of ruling out a server configuration issue.

What I did to try and figure out where it could be going wrong was add a query string to my FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLogin("WhateverPage=WhateverSectionOfCode"); line to try and solve this.  The problem is that when I run the site in IE, it never appends that Query String, which leads me to believe that it never hits any of those "RedirectToLogin" lines.

I know it authenticates, because the code that updates the Last Login timestamp in the database only fires if the user is authenticated.  It looks as if the "RedirectFromLogin" line does go out and find the proper entry in the web.config...and it might actually be redirecting me, but even if it does, it always bounces me back to the login screen.

I've been through all of the really basic ID-10T errors (heh) that could possibly be causing this: Heightened security settings, disabled cookies, etc., but I'm getting the same results on multiple machines.

I'm really sort of stumped as to what to check for next.  I've already had two other sets of eyes on the code, but they couldn't come up with any reason as to why this was happening.  If anyone has any suggestions as to what could be happening, I'd love to hear them.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of IE are you using; specifically, if you're using IE9 then you can use the developer tools to inspect the requeust/response headers.  Otherwise you will need something like Fiddler, but I think that's what you want to look at.

Comment: Is the user still authenticated after getting bounced back to the login page?

Comment: @Coding Gorilla - I'll give Fiddler a try.  I know I've tried this in IE8 and IE7 and neither worked.

Comment: @JamesJohnson - Strange as it sounds, it appears as if they are.

Comment: @CodingGorilla - I checked out Fiddler.  The one big difference I'm noticing is that I get a HTTP 302 status with IE.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @user967255 That's probably what you should be getting; what do you get with the other browsers?

Comment: @CodingGorilla  I get a 200 and the default page I want opens.  I'm trying a few other things.  For the sake of anyone reading this in the future, I'll report on their success or failure.

Comment: Well, I actually got somewhere!  I removed "<authorization><deny users="?"/></authorization>" from my web.config and I actually got a query string to return where it's going wrong!  Now to try and figure out what's going on.

Comment: It seems that somewhere between my login page and my default page the Session is getting lost.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forms Authentication fails to recognize as logged in under IE when underscore in hostname](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144394/forms-authentication-fails-to-recognize-as-logged-in-under-ie-when-underscore-in)

Comment: @user967255  were you able to resolve this issue , i am having same issue and not getting any solution.

Answer (score 4):

i think it is something about cookies..

did you set the domain attribute in the web.config?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" name="cookiename" domain="domain.com" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="60"/>
</authentication>
```

[forms Element for authentication (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx)

Comment: No, I haven't, but I can give that a shot.

Comment: Well, I gave this a try...still no luck.

Answer (score 4):

I know this ticket is a bit old, but apparently IE can't set forms authentication on a domain with an underscore in the name.  So if the issue appeared on a development server that was, say Dev_XP, then IE won't be able to set an authentication cookie.

That's what happened with me.  Here's the link: http://orwin.ca/2012/02/09/formsauthentication-setauthcookie-not-working-in-ie-but-works-in-other-browsers/

This is the KB artical that outlines the issue http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316112

Comment: You have no idea how much time I spent troubleshooting this issue with our dev team. It was only made funnier by my initial reluctance to configure their site using an underscore in the subdomain.

Answer (score -1):

I'm having same issue, but with all other browsers except Chrome. 
The strange thing is that when all these browser are tried locally (in same computer where service is running), everything works well. 
When I'm connecting remotely - only Chrome works. Firefox and IE are redirecting me back to login page every time, though user is authenticated - same as yours, in database logon timestamp updated. 
But I have also developer server, located in the other network, connection to this network takes less time, and here are all three browsers works OK too. 
So I think that the problem is in IIS settings, which might be different on real vs developer server, or it might be a problem in Redirect and thread, which creates session. I found some i[nteresting topic about this](https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_). It's about ASP WebForms though. See [my question on stakoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553149/asp-net-login-does-not-redirect-just-logged-user-properly-in-firefox-and-ie-but). And please, let me know if you solve this problem!