# ASP.NET login does not redirect just logged user properly in Firefox and IE, but works with Chrome

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, simplemembership

I have ASP.NET application, which is perfectly works on development environment. Login works on Firefox, IE and Chrome.
Requests in Firefox in development env looks like:
[image]

POST Request:

```
POST /MyServiceName/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FMyServiceName%2F HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost/MyServiceName/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fMyServiceName%2f
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 171
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken_L00yU3VwcG9ydA2=bQmz8xMlE-u9e0iKr3vtXpCDqo8FpQkcgPzN3cdw2xp73M8SoV_WTwFG5IIY1JEQlHJ-ZHd8h5z_f75FO4nkEcGRhP6e9HBE64rjsGCEVV81
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

And Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /MyServiceName/
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=7D3D9E88072745F5AD2B5FCE038F0A794EF6590F9877A65255A63F124CE4FC3EE0309A03F3ACE9C7C5C39E51050F4009A32558D0FE94F673D7B8D5FEA6E6E2E22BEFF862255B50DFC9B6AC2637C8F04918ECCAD0DD63B29CFCD8B4E9BA4DD898C35C7F7CA8E3BB33DA943CD4A45D80F4F24A1E9EF01829B7258C9195FC977B96; expires=Fri, 28-Sep-2018 09:05:12 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 28 Sep 2018 08:35:12 GMT
Content-Length: 128
```

But when I deploy my service into real server, login in with any browser except Chrome does not work.
Requests in Firefox in real server:
[image]

Remote host POST Request:

```
POST /MyServiceName/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FMyServiceName HTTP/1.1
Host: remhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://remhost/MyServiceName/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fMyServiceName
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 171
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken_L00yU3VwcG9ydA2=-JG3IFQhCVjOuL_SIf7QD0ot7Fc_Fy9lb8Lii_VkLzGKGWswkOPfG-ZQtxijlFYhDO7jAMRiRcatHWcdlBRw7RXVzkdu5864rWiLNWGHc7KSUwgtwA-W_lJHVm-EmKW9v1zEgESa0oQKZ37i9mHC6g2; __RequestVerificationToken_L00yU3VwcG9ydF92Mg2=nAHU2cD63KJZIjm3a8LHUYlZpQ9YChmou1E1pvMfI5xmQl2iqgbJ9x9iCuTH0lDlmAqoqFd5_bnPS3FsUVkNYwYRcLt-WJozs0kWt_jn0fM1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

And Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /MyServiceName
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=BD46865424CAA946E4AF046436F14C10841E64596BDF9125E721000DA2056C5613D914985ED65A1F3ADF65A322D93156559D2F4B02DFB2F3D4C8CCC5837C90CE29825E578FBA2B5E2B1F6E06DC259FC60210C1DA31A44F861476D49A6FFE318474FEE116867B58898357335914B1E8AD65DFEF8223DABDBB07D7ECBAB990D976; expires=Fri, 28-Sep-2018 07:53:36 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Fri, 28 Sep 2018 07:23:36 GMT
Content-Length: 130
```

**GET Request on Firefox**:

```
GET /MyServiceName HTTP/1.1
Host: remhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://remhost/MyServiceName/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fMyServiceName
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken_L00yU3VwcG9ydA2=-JG3IFQhCVjOuL_SIf7QD0ot7Fc_Fy9lb8Lii_VkLzGKGWswkOPfG-ZQtxijlFYhDO7jAMRiRcatHWcdlBRw7RXVzkdu5864rWiLNWGHc7KSUwgtwA-W_lJHVm-EmKW9v1zEgESa0oQKZ37i9mHC6g2; __RequestVerificationToken_L00yU3VwcG9ydF92Mg2=nAHU2cD63KJZIjm3a8LHUYlZpQ9YChmou1E1pvMfI5xmQl2iqgbJ9x9iCuTH0lDlmAqoqFd5_bnPS3FsUVkNYwYRcLt-WJozs0kWt_jn0fM1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

**GET Response on Firefox**:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /MyServiceName/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fMyServiceName
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 28 Sep 2018 07:46:51 GMT
Content-Length: 170
```

**Google Chrome** for remote server:
**POST Login**:

```
curl 'http://remhost/MyServiceName/Account/Login' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Origin: http://remhost' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Save-Data: on' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Referer: http://remhost/MyServiceName/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FMyServiceName%2F' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' -H 'Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken_L00yU3VwcG9ydA2=UcVwtESdo2tT8Uy1opbJpVpDdpBOTYmNXRi0dyW7ubyd529sme8yJ23vQQX4aQlM02NVTMoBowsD4Uzbpydnq_rgd8I2n-G96I5JQ9xgM2E3cnLVys9RNJtbjLwInu1XKdH2VbkqYIaxXP4mWYT-2g2; __RequestVerificationToken_L00yU3VwcG9ydF92Mg2=RANEaw7GedA6EGEajt9O9rDx3k0SPUuWm-gG-nY_GzlpJyr_odsUU3wN6BorEbAz87_yswgZDS07ihDiuUUZxIAfOFdQA2Ohn7HmrlAz1L41' --data '__RequestVerificationToken=eUURMtLNSgIi4SgyID5CJZchnns9yTjK039Z1FFcA7TAQjjZ1wvblnKeseCe7UJu6zclcA3NgZ2rBZnABMGn54maEDhfe5W-kk-mjGeIGIk1&UserName=user&Password=password' --compressed
```

**Request header**:

```
POST /MyServiceName/Account/Login HTTP/1.1
Host: remhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 171
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://remhost
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Save-Data: on
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://remhost/MyServiceName/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FMyServiceName%2F
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken_L00yU3VwcG9ydA2=UcVwtESdo2tT8Uy1opbJpVpDdpBOTYmNXRi0dyW7ubyd529sme8yJ23vQQX4aQlM02NVTMoBowsD4Uzbpydnq_rgd8I2n-G96I5JQ9xgM2E3cnLVys9RNJtbjLwInu1XKdH2VbkqYIaxXP4mWYT-2g2; __RequestVerificationToken_L00yU3VwcG9ydF92Mg2=RANEaw7GedA6EGEajt9O9rDx3k0SPUuWm-gG-nY_GzlpJyr_odsUU3wN6BorEbAz87_yswgZDS07ihDiuUUZxIAfOFdQA2Ohn7HmrlAz1L41
```

**Response header**:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /MyServiceName/
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=33BF43D6803B985EB87EEF8AC1301B63F7A8406ADC73ACED15D3F5737AF883F49D3F64AB979E234A550D554C55B570DAF23AC8FF5A91D8517D70C2E6149341A2DD2F35CFC7B5487141A28099A927C5D971A4C954A2669A8A3E6500E0B762402A366850B5A6F1330740ADB958E43F0044D577AD4E70D517B682AFCA55F9A7482E; expires=Fri, 28-Sep-2018 07:30:09 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Fri, 28 Sep 2018 07:00:09 GMT
Content-Length: 131
```

**GET MyServiceName**/:

```
curl "http://remhost/MyServiceName/" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "Save-Data: on" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Referer: http://remhost/MyServiceName/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=^%^2FMyServiceName^%^2F" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7" -H "Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken_L00yU3VwcG9ydA2=UcVwtESdo2tT8Uy1opbJpVpDdpBOTYmNXRi0dyW7ubyd529sme8yJ23vQQX4aQlM02NVTMoBowsD4Uzbpydnq_rgd8I2n-G96I5JQ9xgM2E3cnLVys9RNJtbjLwInu1XKdH2VbkqYIaxXP4mWYT-2g2; __RequestVerificationToken_L00yU3VwcG9ydF92Mg2=RANEaw7GedA6EGEajt9O9rDx3k0SPUuWm-gG-nY_GzlpJyr_odsUU3wN6BorEbAz87_yswgZDS07ihDiuUUZxIAfOFdQA2Ohn7HmrlAz1L41; .ASPXAUTH=33BF43D6803B985EB87EEF8AC1301B63F7A8406ADC73ACED15D3F5737AF883F49D3F64AB979E234A550D554C55B570DAF23AC8FF5A91D8517D70C2E6149341A2DD2F35CFC7B5487141A28099A927C5D971A4C954A2669A8A3E6500E0B762402A366850B5A6F1330740ADB958E43F0044D577AD4E70D517B682AFCA55F9A7482E" --compressed
```

**Request header**:

```
GET /MyServiceName/ HTTP/1.1
Host: remhost
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Save-Data: on
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://remhost/MyServiceName/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FMyServiceName%2F
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken_L00yU3VwcG9ydA2=UcVwtESdo2tT8Uy1opbJpVpDdpBOTYmNXRi0dyW7ubyd529sme8yJ23vQQX4aQlM02NVTMoBowsD4Uzbpydnq_rgd8I2n-G96I5JQ9xgM2E3cnLVys9RNJtbjLwInu1XKdH2VbkqYIaxXP4mWYT-2g2; __RequestVerificationToken_L00yU3VwcG9ydF92Mg2=RANEaw7GedA6EGEajt9O9rDx3k0SPUuWm-gG-nY_GzlpJyr_odsUU3wN6BorEbAz87_yswgZDS07ihDiuUUZxIAfOFdQA2Ohn7HmrlAz1L41; .ASPXAUTH=33BF43D6803B985EB87EEF8AC1301B63F7A8406ADC73ACED15D3F5737AF883F49D3F64AB979E234A550D554C55B570DAF23AC8FF5A91D8517D70C2E6149341A2DD2F35CFC7B5487141A28099A927C5D971A4C954A2669A8A3E6500E0B762402A366850B5A6F1330740ADB958E43F0044D577AD4E70D517B682AFCA55F9A7482E
```

**Response header**:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 28 Sep 2018 07:00:09 GMT
Content-Length: 4619
```

**Response**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- Here is my html when user logged in -->
</html>
```

The problem seem to be in second GET. On development env it returns status `200 OK`, and on real server `302 Found`.

Authentication is done thru ASP.NET Simple Membership.

Login POST action:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    string errorMsg = "The user name or password provided is incorrect.";
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "Disabled"))
    {
        errorMsg = "Your account has been disabled. Contact administrator for more info.";
    }
    else if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, true))//persistCookie: false))
    {
        accountService.AddLogin(model.UserName);
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", errorMsg);
    return View(model);
}

private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

I have checked login status from server database. The user login was done correctly, and user status is logged in, though Firefox still displays login page as if user is not logged. I think the problem is in redirection somewhere.

Any ideas why? The web.config file is same except database connection settings on both systems. it's same ISS 7.5 on both computers. So what else might be the reason?

One more interesting thing. From the same remote computer where service is run Firefox also works OK. So My problem for remote sessions only.

**UPDATE**:
Seems I found the root cause [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_). But I have no idea yet how to fix it in scope of my code

If the third does not have time to finish before redirect, it might be so, that only remote sessions fail. Agree?

In web.config I have:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
```

Comment: in one environment the 302 is the result of a POST request, in the other it's the result of a GET. Are you sure the same version of the code is running in both cases? Or that you're using the same process to log in? Or that there's no extra rewrite rules present on the IIS server itself? Do both contain an appropriate "Location" header in the response (which would enable the browser to carry out the redirect properly)? You didn't show that

Comment: Hi, it's just screenshot (now updated). But yes, source is same, header location is also same. But I'm not sure about IIS rules. Do you know where this could be checked?

Comment: Hmm. just noticed that location for local service is not displayed. But I think it's not critical? Please, see updated screenshots

Comment: your screenshot of the local one is looking at the wrong request. You need to look at the redirect with the 302 response - that's the one which will contain the location header (since it tells the browser where to redirect to). If there's no location header then the redirect would never work, the browser would not know what to do.

Comment: Re IIS rewrites - this can be in your application's web.config or in IIS config higher up the chain - e.g. at site level or a higher-level virtual directory. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module as a starting point for more info.

Comment: P.S. you say this works in Chrome. It would be sensible to compare the network output in Chrome vs Firefox to see what things are different.

Comment: Hi, Chrome logon to remote service is same as Firefox on local. I.e. there is POST 302 -> 200 GET. I've added POST request and response for both local and remote servres.

Comment: Also added responses from Chrome

Comment: Seems I found the root cause https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_ But I have no idea yet how to fix it in scope of mu code

Comment: sorry can you edit that link, it doesn't seem to work when I click it - get a 404

Comment: Added link to the main topic at the end

Comment: that article is for WebForms not MVC

Comment: Yes, but at least the problem is somewhere in authentication and redirect. Now I understand why do I have this '302 Found', because Firefox counts that I'm not authenticated, and redirects back to logon page. Now need to understand why.

Comment: And one more interesting thing. From the same computer where service run firefox also works Ok. So My problem for remote sessions only.

Comment: " Firefox counts that I'm not authenticated"...technically no, the _server_ decides that you're not authenticated, and tells Firefox where to redirect you to. Firefox just responds to the Location header given in the 302. It has no notion of you being logged in or not.

Comment: The only possible thing I can think of why this might relate to a specific browser is if cookies are not being used correctly by Firefox. Try clearing your cache and all cookies in Firefox, check your cookie settings (especially in relation to the problematic website) close the browser, start a new session and try again. Also maybe try again using a fresh install of Firefox on another machine (or a Virtual Machine) if you can.

Comment: BUT same Firefox browser on same computer does work OK with me development server, which is also a remote server. But in different network. I can attach those logs too if needed. Note, that connection to REAL server takes more time, than to my developer server. So this might be still somehow related to timeout or IIS settings.

Comment: if you're getting a response then it's not timing out, that's for sure. And cookie issues can be specific to a particular site or domain. Did you do as I suggested and clear everything out / test from a different machine? We should rule that out as a possible cause

Comment: Tried both - clear cookies and try from other computer - same. Under "timeout" I meant that session is not established while redirect from POST Login to MyService\ is done. So when then firefox gets to MyService\, it redirecting again to Login view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From you web config `<authentication mode="Forms">`, I can deduct you are using forms authentication.

Try these two things:

1. Set up default url in forms authentication setting like :

   `<authentication mode="Forms">
         <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index"/>
   </authentication>`
2. For redirecting after authentication, instead of using return `RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` or   `return Redirect(returnUrl);`

use `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` method like:

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password) == true)
{
   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
   FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, false);
}
```

It Redirects an authenticated user back to the originally requested URL or the default set in the config.

For more information & override of this method refer :

[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthentication.redirectfromloginpage?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Since I'm using POST Action, I have to return ActionResult, so what I should do in this case? Please, see my public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl) implementation.

Comment: Tried your way and with return null instead return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl); it works now. Thanks a lot!