# Using Javascript setTimeout to call an MVC action to keep alive forms authentication

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery, forms-authentication

I am using setTimeout to call an MVC action to try and keep alive the users forms authentication.

When I call this code normally (ie not using setTimeout) it DOES keep the forms authentication alive.

When called within setTimeout it does not.

**My question is why does this not work when called via setTimeout?**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    DoKeepAlive();    //simple test when page loads....does keep forms auth alive
});


var timeout= 0;
timeout= setTimeout(validationPrompt, 2 * 60 * 1000);  

function validationPrompt() {

    var answer = confirm("Your session will timeout in less than a minute. Click OK to stay logged in, and reset the timout period.")
    if (answer) {

        DoKeepAlive();     //when called in here by setTimeout, does NOT keep forms auth alive

        //re-set the 10 minutes count
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout= setTimeout(validationPrompt, 2 * 60 * 1000); 
    }
    else {
        var URL = "<%= Url.Content("~/Account/Logoff") %>"
        window.location = URL;
    }
}

function DoKeepAlive(){

        var URL = "<%= Url.Content("~/Account/ValidateAuthentication") %>"
    $.post(
            //"../../Account/ValidateAuthentication",      
            URL,
            function(data) {

            }
        );

}
```

Comment: Missing some code? What is "promptUserTimeoutId"? Also, why are you setting "timeout" to the function "validationPrompt"?

Comment: sorry Alejandro, I tried to anonomize my code and made a mess of it - should be clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much frothing back and forth, I discovered today the time on the server I was using was 3 minutes slow. A post on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179500/problem-with-asp-net-forms-authentication-in-internet-explorer) triggered helped me.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say why your code is not working. I would try to simplify it first:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setInterval(function () {
        var answer = confirm("Your session will timeout in less than a minute. Click OK to stay logged in, and reset the timout period.");
        if (answer) {
            $.post('<%= Url.Action("ValidateAuthentication", "Account") %>');
        } else {
            window.location.href = '<%= Url.Action("Logoff", "Account") %>';
        }
    }, 2 * 60 * 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Darin, thanks for the suggestion - same result though, it doesn't work in my live environment :-(

Comment: @james, do you see the AJAX requests being sent? Are they succeeding? Is the timeout of your forms authentication token in web.config higher than `2 * 60 * 1000`?

Comment: They do get sent, but the response I get back is my login page. So it looks like a fresh request that is not authenticated that then redirects to Login. And yes the timeout is higher than in config.

Comment: @james, did you enable slidingExpiration?

Comment: @darin - no, it's not set explicitly but I believe defaults to true.

Comment: @james, yes it defaults to true. Are you running in a web farm?

Comment: @darin - No web farm. I'm clutching at straws now, tried with it explicitly set to True and False, neither helps :-(

Comment: @james, I am afraid I have ran out of ideas. Maybe try lowering the polling interval.

Comment: @darin - thanks for spending some time on this, it's much appreciated!

Comment: James, try using Firebug or Fiddler to examine the POST being sent.  make sure the ASPXAUTH cookie is attached.

Comment: @Darin - After much frothing back and forth, I discovered today the time on the server I was using was 3 minutes slow. A post on this thread triggered helped me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179500/problem-with-asp-net-forms-authentication-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 1):

try putting `timeout= setTimeout(validationPrompt, 2 * 60 * 1000);` inside `$(document).ready` ?

Comment: BTW, did you wait that many seconds to see if it is really working? That is a really long time to wait till you find out :)