# ASPXAUTH cookie not getting generated

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am facing a problem where ASPXAUTH cookie is not being generated unless the website is hit from the same machine where it is hosted. I have confirmed this by enabling and viewing IIS logs.

From all other machines no matter what, it redirects back to the login page. This is a very strange behaviour as no installation has been made nor any changes to IIS. I would appreciate if anybody could share their experience and suggest a possible solution.

UPDATE : For some unkown reasons it is working with Firefox. Still not able to figure out what is causing this in other browsers !

Comment: I have got it working by enabling cookieless authentication in web.config. This issue has been discussed in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179500/problem-with-asp-net-forms-authentication-in-internet-explorer. This doesn't solve my issue 100% and i would still like to know what is causing cookies to disappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After 2.5 days of intense searching and hair pulling it turned out that server date/time was not correct !!! I synchronized it with internet clock and cookies worked.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have security settings where you don't allow cookies in the other browsers?